# Как исключить дубликаты из HQL запроса?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

Есть метод который из таблицы с предложениями о продаже машин выбирает все марки включая дубликаты. Как избавится от дубликатов а уровне запроса?

```
public List<String> getMarks() {

    List<String> result;

    final String hq = "select p.mark from Propose p";

    try (final Session session = factory.get().openSession()) {

        result = session.createQuery(hq, String.class).getResultList();

    }

    return result;
}
```

Вызываю: `result.forEach(System.out::println);` и получаю все значения включая дубликаты. Можно конечно просто в `Set` сразу перекинуть все значения но хотелось бы отсечь дубликаты на уровне запроса. Как это можно сделать?

Таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS propose (
     id SERIAL NOT NULL ,
     id_auhtor INTEGER NOT NULL ,
     sold BOOLEAN NOT NULL ,
     description TEXT NOT NULL ,
     mark TEXT NOT NULL ,
     model TEXT NOT NULL ,
     image BYTEA,
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
     FOREIGN KEY (id_auhtor) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

Comment: скорее всего поможет ключевое слово `distinct`, как-то так: `select distinct p.mark from Propose p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
final String hq = "select DISTINCT p.mark from Propose p";
```